# How to turn echo on in Telnet server using Twisted

Tags: python, twisted, telnet

I am trying to make a simple telnet server that reads lines of user input and answers back with various texts, depending on what is on these lines. After googling around, it seems that the consensus is that `tiwsted` is the best module for this purpose. Unfortunately, it is huge, I'm just getting lost in the documentation and can't make much sense of the published examples. :-(

My current problem is that in some cases the user has to enter a password-like object - i.e., without what he's entering being displayed on the screen. I can turn the echo off by specifying that I'm going to do the echoing myself via `self.transport.will(ECHO)`. Problem is, I can't seem to turn it back on. For instance, `self.transport.wont(ECHO)` has no effect.

Here is some sample code demonstrating the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twisted.conch.telnet import TelnetTransport, StatefulTelnetProtocol, ECHO
from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory
from twisted.application.internet import TCPServer
from twisted.application.service import Application
from twisted.internet import reactor

class TelnetEcho(StatefulTelnetProtocol):

    user = ''
    password = ''
    state = ''

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.ip = self.transport.getPeer().host
        self.transport.write('Welcome\r\n')
        self.transport.write('User: ')
        self.state = 'User'

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if self.state == 'User':
            self.user = line.strip()
            self.transport.will(ECHO)
            self.transport.write('Password: ')
            self.state = 'Password'
        elif self.state == 'Password':
            self.password = line.strip()
            self.transport.write('\r\n> ')
            self.transport.wont(ECHO)
            self.state = 'Prompt'
        elif self.state == 'Prompt':
            if line.strip() == 'quit':
                self.transport.loseConnection()
                return
            self.sendLine(line)
            self.transport.write('> ')
        return

def CreateMyFactory():
    factory = ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = lambda: TelnetTransport(TelnetEcho)
    return factory

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFactory = CreateMyFactory()
    reactor.listenTCP(23, MyFactory)
    reactor.run() else:
    MyFactory = CreateMyFactory()
    service = TCPServer(23, MyFactory)
    application = Application("Telnet Echo Server")
    service.setServiceParent(application)
```

Any help would be appreciated.